# Multiply a column by a scalar in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a N X 2 matrix which I would like to multiply the second column by a certain number.

The matrix looks like this:

```
1   0
6   0
7   0
8   0
4   0.0173000000000000
5   0.0269000000000000
3   0.0720000000000000
2   0.883800000000000
```

But I would like to multiply just the second column by a certain number without affecting the first column. How do I do that in MATLAB?

Comment: `mat1(:,2) = mat1(:,2)*K` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a(:, 2) = a(:,2)*2`
where `a` is your matrix.